# Use named_scope to find number of associated rows (Ruby on Rails + Searchlogic question)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope, searchlogic

Let's say I have:

```
class ForumTopic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :forum_posts
  named_scope :number_of_posts, ??????
end

class ForumPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :forum_topic
end
```

What should I put in ????? to allow searchlogic query like:

```
ForumTopic.descend_by_number_of_posts
```

Any help would be very greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to order by number of posts, right?

I think it's easier if you use `:counter_cache` because if you do, you can order just like this:

```
class ForumTopic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :forum_posts
  named_scope :by_number_of_posts, :order => "forum_posts_count"
end

# controller
ForumTopic.by_number_of_posts.all
```

To use `:counter_cache` you'll need to change the association

```
class ForumPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :forum_topic, :counter_cache => true
end
```

and create a `forum_posts_count` column on `forum_topics` table.

I believe this is it.